# How can I export a function within a React functional component to build a library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, export

I am in the process of creating a React component library, and I have a function within one of my library components that I would like to export. The function, addParticle, is intended to allow users of the library to dynamically add particles to a container by passing props. Here's the code snippet of my component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Particle from "../Particle";
import "./ParticleContainer.css";

export interface AddParticleProps {
  src: string;
  height: string;
  width: string;
  animationDuration: number;
}

interface ParticleContainerProps {
  height?: string;
  width?: string;
  position?: "relative" | "absolute";
}

function ParticleContainer({
  height = "40px",
  width = "40px",
  position,
}: ParticleContainerProps) {
  const [particleDetails, setParticleDetails] = useState<AddParticleProps[]>(
    []
  );

  const addParticle = ({
    src,
    height,
    width,
    animationDuration,
  }: AddParticleProps) => {
    setParticleDetails([
      ...particleDetails,
      { src, height, width, animationDuration },
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="particlesContainer" style={{ height, width, position }}>
      {particleDetails.map((props, index) => {
        return <Particle key={index} id={index} {...props} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export { addParticle }; // How to properly export this function?

export default ParticleContainer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly. `addParticle` is a function within your `ParticleContainer` component, inaccessible from the outside scope - and you can't move it outside because it references the `setParticleDetails` function which is necessary internal to the component (as that is returned from `useState` which, like all React hooks, can *only* be called from inside a function component).

What you can do though, and which is perfectly normal and expected for a React component library, is to export a custom hook to do this. There are a few ways to design the API, depending on what you want consumers to be able to do with  your library, but as a starting point based on what you've already shared, I would guess you want to return an object (an array would also work, but I've gone with an object below) containing both the UI of all the rendered `Particle` component, and the `addParticle` function:

```
function useParticles() {
  const [particleDetails, setParticleDetails] = useState<AddParticleProps[]>(
    []
  );

  const addParticle = ({
    src,
    height,
    width,
    animationDuration,
  }: AddParticleProps) => {
    setParticleDetails([
      ...particleDetails,
      { src, height, width, animationDuration },
    ]);
  };

  const particles = particleDetails.map((props, index) => {
    return <Particle key={index} id={index} {...props} />;
  });

  return { particles, addParticles };
};
```

Once you have this, consumers can easily recreate your proposed `ParticleContainer` component like this:

```
function ParticleContainer({
  height = "40px",
  width = "40px",
  position,
}: ParticleContainerProps) {

  const { particles, addParticle } = useParticles();

  return (
    <div className="particlesContainer" style={{ height, width, position }}>
      {particles}
    </div>
  );
}
```

where the `addParticles` function is not currently used, but can easily be used however the consumer wants to within the component (eg pass it as an `onclick` handler to some button in a child component).

This also decouples the logic of rendering and adding "particles" from the styling of the container component (the width, height and position) - the `ParticleContainer`, or whatever alternative a consumer wants to use for a container, contains that information, and the `useParticles` hook is looking after the logic of adding the particles themselves.